# count and print the unique number of strings

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file as shown below. I would like to count the unique number of connections of each person in the first and second column. Third column is the ID numbers of first column persons and fourth column is the ID numbers of second column persons.

```
susan  ali   156  294
susan  ali   156  294
susan  anna  156  67
rex    rex   432  564
rex    rex   432  564
philip sama  543  22
```

for example, susan has two connections with ali and anna. susan's ID is 156. Ali's and anna's ID are 294, 67 respectively. In the ouput, last column is the number of connections of each person. Total connections are the sum of the connections of each person.

your help would be appreciated!!

output:

```
susan  156  :- ali    294  anna  67   2
rex    432  :- rex    564             1
philip 543  :- sama   22              1
ali    294  :- susan  156             1
anna   67   :- susan  156             1
rex    564  :- rex    432             1
sama   22   :- philip 543             1

Total connections:-8
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `ali    294  :- susan  156             1`?

Comment: @perreal ali is connected to susan. no:of connection is one(unique).

Answer (score 0):

a simple cat ztest.txt | sort -k1,2 | uniq -c does the trick , but since you want it formatted - you can use awk like this :
awk '{ print $2 " :- " $4 "  connected to " $3 " :- " $5 "-- count: " $1} '

full command :

```
$ cat ztest.txt | sort -k1,2 | uniq -c |  awk '{ print $2 " :- " $4 "  connected to " $3 " :- " $5 "-- count: " $1} '
```

output :

```
 philip  :-  543   connected to  sama  :-  22  -- count:  1
 rex    :-  432   connected to  rex  :-  564  -- count:  2
 susan  :-  156   connected to  ali  :-  294  -- count:  2
 susan  :-  156   connected to  anna  :-  67  -- count:  1
```

Comment: its sorted !! , if you want some other arrangement you can try a thing or two with awk i checked with "philip  :-  543   connected to  sama  :-  22  -- count:  1" its same as yours.  if you are refering to your line : "susan  156  :- ali    294  anna  67   2"  .... i didnt put code to list all other connections ... thought they were just for the example , the main task was to get connections and count based on unique matches of the first coloumn which "cat ztest.txt | sort -k1,2 | uniq -c" does.  Are you looking for something else ?